# evaluation of $\int\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\displaystyle \int\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ $\displaystyle \int\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1}dx = \int\frac{\left(x^5+x+1\right)-(x+1)}{x^5+x+1}dx = x-\int\frac{x+1}{x^5+x+1}dx$

Now Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{x+1}{x^5+x+1}dx = \int \frac{x+1}{(x^2+x+1)\cdot (x^3-x^2+1)}$

Now I Did not understand how can i solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E5+%2F+%28x%5E5+%2B+x+%2B+1%29) gives a rather nasty answer. I'd guess that one should factor $x^3 - x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and do partial fractions on the result.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $1-\int \text{blah}$ at the end of the second line because $(x^5+x+1)/(x^5+x+1)=1$? This follows from simple long division of $x^5$ by $x^5+x+1$.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life after integrating that 1 becomes x (power rule).

Comment: @AGoogler Of course, foolish to try to read so late at night for me.

Answer (score 3):

A very nasty solution:

You have observed that $x^5 + x + 1 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 - x^2 + 1)$. This means that you can factor $x^5 + x + 1$ into linear factors :$x^5 + x + 1 = \prod_{i=1}^5 (x-\alpha_i)$, where $\alpha_i$ can be computed. Thus, for any polynomial $p(x)$ or degree less than $5$ you can find unique constants $c_i$ such that:
$$ \frac{p(x)}{x^5 + x + 1 } = \sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{c_i}{x - \alpha_i}$$
Now, each of these terms can be integrated:
$$ \int \frac{p(x)}{x^5 + x + 1 } dx = \sum_{i=1}^5  c_i \ln(x - \alpha_i).$$
So, in principle - problem solved! But please, don't ask me to do the actual computations. Wolfram can do it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Note that\begin{align}
&\frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1} 
=1-\frac{2x+3}{7(x^2+x+1)}+
\frac{2x^2-x-4}{7(x^3-x^2+1)}\\
 =& \ 1-\frac{2x+1}{7(x^2+x+1)}-\frac{2}{7(x^2+x+1)} +
\frac{2(3x-2x)}{21(x^3-x^2+1)} +
\frac{x-12}{21(x^3-x^2+1)}
\end{align}
Then
$$\int \frac{x^5}{x^5+x+1} dx
=x -\frac1{21}\ln\frac{(x^2+x+1)^3}{(x^3-x^2+1)^2}
-\frac4{7\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}+\frac1{21}K
$$
where
$$K = \int \frac{x-12}{x^3-x^2+1}dx$$
$x^3-x^2+1= (x-a)(x^2-\frac x{a^2}-\frac1a) $ has a single real root $a=-0.7549$, or
$$a =\frac13\bigg( 1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{25+3\sqrt{69}}2}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{25-3\sqrt{69}}2}\bigg)
$$
which allows $K$ to be integrated below with partial fractions
\begin{align}
K= &\int\frac{x-12}{(x-a)(x^2-\frac x{a^2}-\frac1a)}dx\\
=& \ \frac1{a^3-2}\int
 \frac{a(a-12)}{x-a}+ \frac{a(12-a)(2x-\frac1{a^2})}{2(x^2-\frac x{a^2}-\frac1a)}+ \frac{12a^2-\frac6a-\frac32}{x^2-\frac x{a^2}-\frac1a}\ dx\\
=& \ \frac1{a^3-2}\bigg(\frac{a(a-12)}{2}\ln\frac{(x-a)^2}{x^2-\frac x{a^2}-\frac1a}
+\frac {a^2-16a-4}{\sqrt{-4a^3-1}}\tan^{-1}\frac{2a^2x-1}{\sqrt{-4a^3-1}}\bigg)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x+1}{(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)}=\frac{2x+3}{7(x^2+x+1)}-\frac{2x^2-x-4}{7(x^3-x^2+1)}$$

Comment: @achille : sorry i have edited.